# Converting global coordinates into set of local matrices for ik skeleton creation

Tags: algorithm, matrix, rotation, coordinates, quaternions

I have the 3d global positions of a set of joints as they move over time and the ik skeleton structure which relates them. I am currently writing some code to convert this information in .bvh file. I understand the .bvh structure, but what I need to do for each frame is convert the global coordinates into a series of local matrices which represent the transformation to "move" from parent to child for each node.

What I don't know how to do is calculate the local matrix for the transformation for instance to go from

rootNode = (Rx,Ry,Rz) and lets presume that initial orientation is in line with the global axes

to

child1 = (Cx,Cy,Cz)

and so on.

Any help much appreciated.